# Обновить содержимое списка DrawMenu (Android)

Tags: java, android, drawerlayout

У меня есть Активити "G" с реализованным в нем DrawMenu, содержимое DrawMenu собираю из базы и вставляю в DrawMenu при создании Aктивити "G".
В дальнейшем при выборе элементов из DrawMenu содержимое также изменяется...

Вот у меня проблема с обновлением содержимого DrawMenu.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.drawer_main, container, false);
        mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectItem(position);
            }
        });

        Data.aAdapter = Data.getAnswerAdapter(getActionBar().getThemedContext());
        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(Data.aAdapter);
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);

        return mDrawerListView;
    }
```

и...

```
/**
     * Метод создания адаптера для формироваия списка ответов
     * @param /sAnswers
     * @param /context
     * @return
     */
    public static ArrayAdapter<String> getAnswerAdapter(Context context){
        return new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, sAnswers());
    }

    /**
     * Метод создания масива с ответами
     */
    public static String[] sAnswers(){
        String[] sAnswers ={"Варианты ответов","","","","","","",};
        crsr.moveToFirst();
        for(int i = 1;i<crsr.getCount()+1;i++){
            sAnswers[i] = crsr.getString(crsr.getColumnIndex(Data.A_TABLE_TEXT));
            if (!crsr.moveToNext()) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return sAnswers;
    }
```

Базу открываю и обновляю таким методом

```
public static void runDB(Context context, int ID_Q) {
        //Создал объект БД
        try {
            db = new Data(context);
            crsr = QuestionGenerator.getAnswers(db, ID_Q);
            sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    crsr,
                    new String[]{"_id", Data.A_TABLE_TEXT},
                    new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                    0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Вариант с aAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() не работает...

В тупике, дело стало, инфы чего-то конкретной не найду(

по поводу `CursorLoadManager`

работа с базой организована как в примере 
http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/278-urok-136-cursorloader.html
но у меня в одном классе идет инициация, а обновление должно быть в другом активити.

```
public class Main_f extends FragmentActivity implements View.OnClickListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{
    static Button bGame;
    static Button bOption;
    static Button bQuit;
    static Button[] bForMain;
    static LinearLayout ll;
    static LinearLayout lButtons;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_frame);

        ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lMain);
        ll.setOnClickListener(this);

        lButtons = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lButtons);
        lButtons.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        bGame = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bNewGame);
        bOption = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSettings);
        bQuit = (Button)  findViewById(R.id.bQuit);

        bForMain = new Button[]{bGame, bOption, bQuit};
        for(Button b:bForMain){
            b.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.bNewGame:
                Data.runDB(this, 0);
                getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
                Intent aNewGame = new Intent(this, Game_f.class);
                startActivity(aNewGame);
                break;
        }
    }
```

а вызывать хочу в

```
public class Game_f extends ActionBarActivity implements DrawMenu.NavigationDrawerCallbacks, View.OnClickListener{
    public static String sString;
    public static TextView tvQuestion;
    public static String sQuestion;

    private DrawMenu mAnswersVariable;
    private CharSequence mAnswer;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game_frame);

        mAnswersVariable = (DrawMenu) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mAnswer = getTitle();

        tvQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tV_H);
        tvQuestion.setOnClickListener(this);
        tvQuestion.setText(QuestionGenerator.getQuestion(0));

        mAnswersVariable.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
    }

 public void onClick(View v){
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.tV_H:
                //TODO написать метод обновления списка ответов
                Data.runDB(this, 0);
                tvQuestion.setText(QuestionGenerator.getQuestion(0));
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

при работе с адаптерами получающими данные из курсора, для его обновления  сначала нужно запросить данные о новом курсоре:

```
Adapter.changeCursor()
```

или

```
Adapter.swapCursor()
```

в зависимости от того, что вам больше подходит в текущей ситуации, потом уже (при необходимости) делать:

```
Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Однако лучшим решением при работе с БД, будет использовать класс `CursorLoader`, который проследит за жизненным циклом курсора при поворотах и позаботится о его закрытии при ненадобности

Comment: добавил в вопрос инфу по вашему предложению, вопрос теперь в том как использывать метод `CursorLoader` пир инициализации в одном активити, а вот метод востановления должен быть в другом активити....

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего вам надо лишь уведомить адаптер списка о произошедших изменениях в данных. Для этого у адаптера есть метод `notifyDataSetChanged()`, коий вызовет перерисовку элементов адаптера. Т.е. в коде это должно выглядеть как-то так:

```
listView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```